# How to remove the Theme Customization Button from the dashboard and themes options page?

Tags: theme-development, filters, hooks, theme-customizer

In my Wordpress theme that I've currently been building I do not take advantage of the Wordpress Theme Customization API. As much as I would like too, I've invested far too much time into my own personal theme options framework for changing things.

This leads me to my question. How do I remove the blue, "Customize Your Site" button from the dashboard as well as link shown when viewing Appearance > Themes? I did some Googling, but my Google-Fu failed and couldn't find a solution that didn't use CSS or Javascript.

Ideally a hook to remove it would be best. But if there is no clean way to do so, a JS and or CSS solution would be fine.

Comment: If you don't hook your Theme's options into the Theme Customizer, why would you need to hide the Theme Customizer entirely? It is a convenient way to modify Header, Background, Front Page display settings, Site Title and Tagline, etc. and preview those changes in real-time. So: why the need to remove it? Also: there's no reason you couldn't hook your "own personal theme options framework" into the Theme Customizer (and would provide a great benefit to your Theme users in the process).

Comment: I want to remove it because it is confusing. People assume they can change theme settings via this button but in my theme you can't. As good as the inbuilt theme customisation API is, it has limitations and is far from an out of the box solution. It can be extended of course, but I'm working off of a library that I built which supports things I'd have to code in support for via the new API of which would take considerable time to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the lastest version of WordPress (4.3) you can now natively remove the customizer's theme switch setting without resorting to CSS hacks.

```
/**
 * Remove customizer options.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 * @param object $wp_customize
 */
function ja_remove_customizer_options( $wp_customize ) {
   //$wp_customize->remove_section( 'static_front_page' );
   //$wp_customize->remove_section( 'title_tagline'     );
   //$wp_customize->remove_section( 'nav'               );
   $wp_customize->remove_section( 'themes'              );
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'ja_remove_customizer_options', 30 );
```

Comment: You are correct (and welcome). I have chosen your answer as the correct one as the original was always just a hack around the problem. A native solution is more bulletproof.

Answer (score 4):

In the latest version of WordPress, the themes section is a panel, so it must be removed as follows:

```
add_action( 'customize_register', 'prefix_remove_customizer_options', 30 );
/**
 * Remove customizer options.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 * @param object $wp_customize The current WordPress customizer object.
 */
function prefix_remove_customizer_options( $wp_customize ) {
    $wp_customize->remove_panel( 'themes' );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will fully remove the menu option:

```
add_action('admin_menu', function () {
    global $submenu;

    foreach ($submenu as $name => $items) {
        if ($name === 'themes.php') {
            foreach ($items as $i => $data) {
                if (in_array('customize', $data, true)) {
                    unset($submenu[$name][$i]);

                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Other answers don't remove it if you are on another subpage + you hover themes menu (you'll see it in submenus)

Answer (score 0):

There are [no hooks](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5/wp-admin/includes/dashboard.php#L1257) to that part of the Dashboard.

It has to be done with CSS (or jQuery if you want to convert it in another thing).

```
add_action( 'admin_head-index.php', 'hide_customize_button_wpse_82424' );

function hide_customize_button_wpse_82424(){
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">div.welcome-panel-column:first-child {display:none;} </style>
    <?php
}
```

**[update]**

As pointed by @helenhousandi in a comment:

> the `wp_welcome_panel()` function is added on the `welcome_panel` hook, but no, there are (purposefully) no hooks inside that function.

So, another approach is to remove the action hook and recreate the `wp_welcome_panel()` function, like so:

```
add_action( 'load-index.php', 'remove_welcome_panel' );
function remove_welcome_panel()
{
    remove_action( 'welcome_panel', 'wp_welcome_panel' );
    add_action( 'welcome_panel', 'my_welcome_panel' );
}
```

And `my_welcome_panel` is a replica of **[`wp_welcome_panel()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5/wp-admin/includes/dashboard.php#L1257)** adapted as one wishes.

***Please, also note her observation:*** <sup>my emphasis</sup>

> *I would suggest against having a publicly distributed theme remove it*, though, because a user may come to expect that it's there. We found in user testing that many new users returned to that welcome panel even after getting acquainted.

Comment: Oh, that's a shame. Thank you very much for posting your solution, it works well!

Comment: Actually, the `wp_welcome_panel()` function is added on the `welcome_panel` hook, but no, there are (purposefully) no hooks inside that function. It's more a use it as is, replace it with what works better for you/client/whomever, or remove it kind of thing. I would suggest against having a publicly distributed theme remove it, though, because a user may come to expect that it's there. We found in user testing that many new users returned to that welcome panel even after getting acquainted.

Comment: @helenhousandi, thanks for the feedback! I've updated the Answer accordingly (:hopefully:).

Comment: sorry to dig this up, but where would one have to add the code you posted in your answer? In the `admin.php` file or in `functions.php` of my theme?

Answer (score 0):

You need to Pass the following code at function.php

```
function theme_option_remove( $wp_customize ) {
$wp_customize->remove_section("themes");
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'theme_option_remove' ,20 );
```